# How to get Navigation Controller if it is not set as Is initial view controller?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am working on one app and for this i have used SWRevealViewController library for showing left side Menu. As per SWRevealViewController guide I have not set navigation controller as my **Is Initial View Controller** on storyboard. So how do I get Navigation controller in such scenario? because I need to access navigation controller's root view controller.

[image: Find image description here]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "So how do I get Navigation controller" That depends who "I" is. Where is the code that needs to get the navigation controller?

Comment: if you are used the SWL is the initial VC, if you are used the login in before SWL then you can get Navigation controller in this scenario

Comment: You should have to use the SWRevealViewController as an rootviewController and Use Login view as contentViewController. So in this way it will be appear in the Starting. After login you have to redirect it to HomeViewController where is the slide menu button is available for open the Slide menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension of UIApplication through which you can get top view controller

```
extension UIApplication {

    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}
```

After getting topViewController from this

```
if let _topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {

   /// place your logic here 
}
```

you can check _topController is Navigation Controller or SWReveal Controller if it is SWReveal you can access your front view controller and place your further logic.